# Can I get option elements from another file?

Tags: html, forms, html-select

I'm working on creating a basic Naming Convention app. I've created a **basic structure** for it. The `form` has `select` elements and from dropdown, user will pick the best suitable `option`.

But there's one select element that has over **300+ different option**. And using them in index.html is **a lot of lines** and **readibility is horrible**. Is there any way I can get option's from another file so that my html file would look clean?

Thanks in advance :)

I've searched online but none of those solutions resolved my problem. I just want a basic solution.

Comment: I think you could use Javascript to import the options. That being say, I would be more worried about _usability_ of the web page itself than _readability_ of the HTML.  300+ options is a lot to go through.

Comment: Look for Ajax and Paging

Comment: I'm looking if there's an easy way like referring an HTML file/element or using JS. @mplungjan But I guess JS is a good way to go.

Comment: It's just a local project, we're not going to publish it, so usability is not our concern but thanks for the heads up! @KIKOSoftware

Comment: Actually, you should populate the SELECT options on the **backend**, and serve it to the client that way. You can also use a templating engine. Once you **build** the project the options will be populated automatically into the desired page's element by the engine. For example https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/builtin-helpers.html#each. Otherwise, yes, JS's AJAX (`fetch` API) can do the trick.

Comment: I see, thanks for the tip! I'll consider this option also @RokoC.Buljan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put your select options to the template at the bottom of the index page. Then use JavaScript to populate the list.

```
<html>
<body>
    <!-- Your HTML here... -->
    <form method="GET">
        <select id="mySelect" name="list"></select>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <!-- Other html... -->
    <!-- Options at the bottom of the file -->
    <script id="options" type="html/template">
        <option value="1">A</option>
        <option value="2">B</option>
        <option value="3">C</option>
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var options = document.getElementById("options");
        var list = document.getElementById("mySelect");
        list.innerHTML = options.innerHTML;
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

In practice, however, such a long list of options is populated using server-side templates or dynamically loaded content. The solution depends on the technological stack. If you develop a small web application that will be hosted on a web server, you might want to consider JavaScript [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) function.

Index.htm:

```
<html>
<body>
    <!-- Your HTML here... -->
    <form method="GET">
        <select id="mySelect" name="list"></select>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <!-- Other html... -->
    <!-- JavaScript to populate the list -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        const request = (async () => {
            const response = await fetch("List.htm");
            const options = await response.text();

            var list = document.getElementById("mySelect");

            list.innerHTML = options;
        })();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

List.htm:

```
<option value="1">A</option>
<option value="2">B</option>
<option value="3">C</option>
```

Answer (score -2):

Main html file:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <object name="combo" type="text/html" data="b.html">
        </object>
    </body>
</html>
```

Included content (b.html) :

```
<select id="combo1">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="3">4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Yes! That's the answer I'm looking for. I should use <object> then. Thanks for your help @shahram alemzadeh

Comment: This answer is incorrect. If you have a `<form>` (and OP has one!) this suggestion will not work if you need to submit the data. Also, styling the Object element kind of s... brings up new problems to the desk.

Comment: Actually, I have one more question to ask you mate. How can I keep the CSS and JS but use this object? I've tried with adding <select> <object> </select> but it didn't worked. Is there any way to fix that, or I am forced to not use CSS, JS with object element? Thanks :) @shahram alemzadeh

Comment: Yeah, I just realized that @RokoC.Buljan And yeah I got failed when tried to submit either way. The way shahram replied is correct but not works for me.

Comment: @icardiyolog1905 no, it's not correct since you stated that you use a form. That's just an invalid suggestion/answer.

Comment: Yeah you're right :( @RokoC.Buljan